# Process shows parent process name as "Non-existent process"

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, process

For our office use we have created a .net application(schedule.exe) which runs in continuously for full day. This application does runs other application on a scheduled basic(not by using windows scheduled task). In that we have feature which check for new rows in table every hour and if found then we run a application(notification.exe) which shows new notification to user, if new rows not found then we don't run it. We use shellexecute command to run notification.exe from my schedule.exe.and I also tried with process.start command.

Now the problem is sometimes notification.exe runs even if new rows not present( it runs even if it not triggered) .There is no particular sequence to recreate the error. I dint find any problem in my code also.

So i just used process explorer to check it. In usual case notification.exe has schedule.exe as parent process. In case of error it had parent process as Non-existent process.So this is the only difference i got which may help to troubleshoot the error. So if a process has "Non-existent process"  as parent then what does it mean? Also how can I troubleshoot my problem?

Comment: Add tracing to your code.

Comment: @HansPassant tracing should be added within code  or any external program can help me to do the same?